# Tcp high performance server/framework and configuration to use on Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, signalr, zeromq

We need to write high performance tcp server and using azure as a hosting.
We have several options:

1. Wrte custom tcp server in c# like described there http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/17/Creating-an-external-facing-Azure-Worker-Role-endpoint.aspx. But we don't want to reinvent a wheel.
2. Use WCF(probably best way). In that case we need good knowledge of how to configure it because there are a lot of configuration options. Could somebody recommend some configuration? And should we use wroker role hosting or IIS hosting?
3. Signal/R. As I understand it has version one and currently is production ready and can be used as tcp server. Which is better and more performant signalR or WCF? Should we use wroker role hosting or IIS hosting?
4. Zero/C ICE. Do somebody use it?
5. Use ZeroMQ C# bindings like described here http://zguide.zeromq.org/cs:asyncsrv

Unfortunately we still don't know some details about our protocol(but it will be binary) and so on. So we need a possibility to easilly change some server behaviour without big code changes.

Also it would be great to know how azure's load ballancer might affect server behaviour.

Comment: You could also check my networking library: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/11/new-version-of-griffin-networking-a-networking-library-for-net/ and http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-networking-a-somewhat-performant-networking-library-for-net/

Comment: First, if you need raw TCP, SignalR will not help you. SignalR works over HTTP in all cases to get started, though it can upgrade to WebSockets from there if both client and server support them. That said, I think you need to provide a little more detail about exactly what kind of things you need to communicate and what exactly your performance requirements are if you're going to get a *good* answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I found that:

1. Writing custom tcp server is our only choice.
2. It is possible to do in WCF but very difficult because we need to use custom binding witch custom message encoder and this is very difficult in our case.
3. Signal/R is not suitable for us because it is by design for other kinds of tasks. Not for generic TCP server.
4. Not found any info about that.
5. ZeroMQ is really good and it supports tcp request reply style and multicasting but it forces us to use zmq on client side becaue it uses custom framing. Unfortunately our client side implemented in hardware and it is not possible to add zmq at all.

Comment: You can use 0MQ with raw sockets, i.e. plain TCP/IP, using the ZMQ_ROUTER_RAW option. You can then talk to existing clients using their old protocol, and use 0MQ's own protocols elsewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately clrzmq doesn't support it now.